# UIWebView has a delay when the load image from url

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uiwebview

I have problem with `UIWebView` delay when the load image from url.

In my code are lines to load local html file:

```
NSBundle *thisBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *path = [thisBundle pathForResource:@"detail" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:html, imageURL];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

and one of lines in my detail.html file:

```
<img src="%@" height="100%" alt="…"></img>
```

And now when I push the button and go to UIWebView, at first it is white and after few seconds show image and text. 
I know that time is necessary to load image from URL, but is it possible at first show text and next waiting to load image??

Generally I thinking of: push button -> go to `UIWebView` -> show text -> show image when it's loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of **Martin H**, I managed to solve the problem.

First in my local.html file, I was add in `<head>` section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadImage(imageSource) {
         document.getElementById("picture").src=imageSource;
    }
</script>
```

next in `<body>` section:

```
<img src="" style="border: none;" id="picture">
```

and next in my UIViewController I was add delegate method:

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)web {
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"loadImage('http://example.com/image.jpg')"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could do, one would be to just display a view underneath the uiwebview that displays the text.
Set the uiwebview's alpha to be 0 (so its transparent), then when you receive notification that the uiwebview has finished loading use an animation to fade it in, and then remove the view with text.

You will know when the UIWebView has finished loading when the webViewDidFinishLoad: is called.

For the animation something like this:

```
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                 animations:^ {
                     self.webView.alpha = 1.0;                         
                 }];
```

Comment: Solution that you described is theoretically good, but I would like to keep only the UIWebView, if it's possible of course.

Comment: Then you'll have to use javascript to control what appears in your webview and when.

Comment: **Martin H,** can you write more how to do this with javascript??

Comment: I'm not an expert in JavaScript, you'd be better off asking a specific new question on this using Javascript/html tags in the question (its nothing specifically to do with iOS). If the web page does not belong to you and thus you cannot add the JS to the page itself then it can be injected into the page's dom via UIWebView using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString. IMO this is going to be about 10 times more effort then just using another UIView if you don't know Javascript. Why don't you want to use another UIView? You could have it working in 5 minutes.